# How do I get multiple listeners for each Button in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a class `public class StoreListViewActivity extends Activity implements
             OnItemClickListener`
that has a method `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id)` that I don't think I have a use for because this is a listener for the entire area of the list. What I want is to have buttons with different listeners and images in place of where the button is, but with my implementation (of the onBuyButtonClick method), I only have one listener and all the other "Buy!" buttons all use that same listener because I'm using the `Button bb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buy_button);` so they are all the same button. What I want is:

`---------------------------------`

`[image] Fruit Ninja is..... [Buy!]` --> buy button has its own listener (i.e. decrease balance)

`---------------------------------`

`[image] Subway Surfers is.. [Buy!]` --> buy button has its own listener (i.e. takes you to play store)

`---------------------------------`

and if possible, could I have images in place of that Buy button with my implementation? I have a ButtonView on the right side of the ListView and when I try to add an ImageView there too, the app crashes

I have a button on the right of each list that has different functions. In my `StoreListViewActivity` class, I have objects:

```
public static final Integer[] images = 
    { R.drawable.fruit_ninja,
      R.drawable.subway_surfers };

public static final Spanned[] titles = new Spanned[]
    { Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "Fruit Ninja" + "</b>" + " is selling " +
                    "<b>" + "20 Starfruits" + "</b>" + " for " + "<b>" +
                    "100" + "</b>" + " Coins!"),
      Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "Subway Surfers" + "</b>" + " is selling " +
                    "<b>" + "5 Paint-Powered Jetpacks" + "</b>" + " for " + "<b>" +
                    "150" + "</b>" + " Coins!") };

public static final String[] buy =
    { "Buy!", "Buy!" };
```

These objects go in an ArrayList and get displayed in a ListView in the onCreate method:

```
// Android ID
private String android_id;

ListView storeListView;
List<StoreRowItem> storeRowItems;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // no title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // set full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // inflate ListView
    setContentView(R.layout.store);
    // get android id
    android_id = 
            Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), 
                             Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    // set text for balance
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.store_header2);
    try {
        tv.setText("  My Balance:                                     "
                    + //static method to grab balance);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // store items for current game
    storeRowItems = new ArrayList<StoreRowItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        StoreRowItem item = new StoreRowItem(images[i], titles[i], buy[i]);
        storeRowItems.add(item);
    }

    size = storeRowItems.size();
    storeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.store_list2);
    StoreListViewAdapter adapter = new StoreListViewAdapter(this,
                                    R.layout.store_list_row, storeRowItems);
    // can select buttons
    storeListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    // disable focus on the list items
    storeListView.setFocusable(false);
    storeListView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    storeListView.setClickable(false);

    storeListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    storeListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

for reference, this is my `store_list_row.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

<!--  Application Icon -->
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/store_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/store_list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Title-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/store_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/store_thumbnail"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="75dp"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

 <!-- Rightend Button -->
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/buy_button"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/buy_button_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my adapter:

```
public class StoreListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StoreRowItem> {

Context storeContext;

public StoreListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<StoreRowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.storeContext = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    Button buttonView;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    StoreRowItem storeRowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) storeContext
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.store_list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_list_image);
        holder.buttonView = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buy_button);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.buttonView.setText(storeRowItem.getBuy());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(storeRowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(storeRowItem.getImageId());

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

In the `getView` method, set a `tag` for each button so that you can identify the button later when the button is clicked.

```
  holder.buttonView.setTag(storeRowItem.getTitle());
```

And when the button is clicked, get the `tag` of the button clicked, and do suitable action based on the `tag`.

```
holder.buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String title = v.getTag().toString();

                    if (title.equals("Title1")) {
                        //Do something
                    }

                    else if (title.equals(("Title2")) {
                        //Do something
                    }

                }
            });
```

Here is the complete code for `Adapter`

```
public class StoreListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StoreRowItem> {

        Context storeContext;

        public StoreListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                List<StoreRowItem> items) {
            super(context, resourceId, items);
            this.storeContext = context;
        }

        /*private view holder class*/
        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView txtTitle;
            Button buttonView;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            StoreRowItem storeRowItem = getItem(position);

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) storeContext
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.store_list_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_title);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_list_image);
                holder.buttonView = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buy_button);



                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            holder.buttonView.setText(storeRowItem.getBuy());
            holder.txtTitle.setText(storeRowItem.getTitle());
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(storeRowItem.getImageId());
            holder.buttonView.setTag(storeRowItem.getTitle());

            holder.buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String title = v.getTag().toString();

                    if (title.equals("Title1")) {
                        //Do something
                    }

                    else if (title.equals(("Title2")) {
                        //Do something
                    }

                }
            });

            return convertView;
            }
        }
```